why did the homepage button go down from the row of other menu items when I deleted text within the navigator information?
I deleted text within the navigator information (marked in yellow below) to delete text in the header of the website.
Why did the Homepage button (marked in red below) go down from the row of other menu items?
I must've deleted something crucial in the navigator info when I went to delete the text in the header.


You have a second link (<a> tag) above the Home link in your menu.
It's linking to careers.
Maybe you will look in your menu settings.

So that's what making my 'Homepage' button goes down? or it's another setting i have to look up the menu settings like u said? Thank you.

Oh my goodness you're right, my 'homepage' button returned to normal. You're such a lifesaver! Thank you so much! i'll tell this to my colleague about you haha. Thanks again!
